# Drupal 7 Autocomplete

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, drupal, autocomplete, drupal-7

An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: htps://MYSITE/index.php?q=user/autocomplete
StatusText: 
ResponseText: 
ReadyState: 4

I get that error when I try to type in the autocomplete box that is installed from core drupal.

I've read up on documentation on patching these files https://www.drupal.org/node/1232416 and did so. 
In my console I get an error of : 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load htps://SITE_B. Redirect from htps://ANOTHERSITE' to 'htps://SITE_B' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'htps://MYSITE' is therefore not allowed access.

So I researched CORS and added htp://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin
suggestion about .htaccess but to no avail.

I'm running drupal 7.51 on Dev Desktop 2 on a localhost. As well I have it running live, but want to fix it locally first. Any suggestions will help, I've research for hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless hours and cold showers, I found out my answer. There was a bad php script in one of the nodes that used Drupal_goto(). That is how I got XMLHttpRequest. I followed https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22825/how-to-find-bad-php-node-that-makes-search-cron-fail to find out where my php script failed me at.